# How can i get the content of the DOM that is on another page which i access by clicking a button using JSDOM (webscraping)

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I am scraping a website and using JSDOM and nodejs for it. The data that i need to get isn't located on the homepage but on another page that i visit when i click the button for search.
I have created a dom using JSDOM package and selected that button and i have created a code for simulating a click on it, here it is:

```
 result.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log('test');
       
    });
    var evt = dom.window.document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("click", false, true);
    result.dispatchEvent(evt)
```

so the console does print 'test' but i don't how to access now that new dom that is supposed to appear  when you click on this button so that i can access data from it. That button doesn't have href in it just a function that opens up a new page on click and now i don't know how to access that new page after and should i create a new dom for it like i did for the homepage?